# Adding JQuery UI Resizable after Adding Object in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

When I add an object to a list of JQuery Resizable objects in my Meteor app, the object is not re-sizable until I refresh the page.

What kind of event listener or something should I add, and where?

I figured my code wasn't necessary for this question, but I will definitely put it up if requested.

Thanks,
--Nick

> **EDIT:** A note for future readers of this question (if any), I decided
>   to go with ryanswapp:interactjs. Worked right out of the box. The less
>   JQuery the better (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way to init UI elements in a list is by creating a template for each item, then use the `onRendered` event of the template to execute the function.

**list.html**

```
...
<ul>
    {{#each items}}
        {{> ItemTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
...
```

**item-template.html**

```
<template name="ItemTemplate">
    <li>
        <div class="resizable">
            {{content}}
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

**item-template.js**

```
Template.ItemTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    this.find('.resizable').resizable();
});
```

Comment: Definitely the most logical way to do it. Kind-of wanted to avoid splitting them up, but it'll give me a lot more options. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A note for future readers of this question (if any), I decided to go with ryanswapp:interactjs. Worked right out of the box. The less JQuery the better (in my opinion).